# Bearings on PAMGuard

Tags: pamguard, array, porpoise, towed, bearing

I've been using PAMGuard's click detector + TMA module on a towed array dataset (four-channel soundtrap) to get localisations of finless porpoises. I get very strange results when I use the new version (2.02.03) vs the old one (1.15.17) (Images attached of the same sound file folder). I am using the exact same hydrophone array file and the same click detector settings. The user groups are also the same (hydrophone 1-2 as group 0 and 2-3 as group 1). Ive tried keeping the echo detector on and discarding echoes but nothing seems to fix the problem. I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't figure out what. Any suggestions would be really helpful!
[image: PAMGuard Version 1.15.17]
[image: PAMGuard Version 2.02.03]

Comment: Have you tried re-running the time delay and bearing calculations in viewer mode? Press the coloured dots icon at the top of the display to bring up the re-processing dialog.

Comment: If that doesn't work, please email support@pamguard.org with a sample of data and we'll look into it.

Answer (score 4):

For a problem like this, you may be better off contacting PAMGuard support: support@pamguard.org, ideally uploading a small sample of data and we'll take a look.